# What is the cause of the Null Reference Exception for the below?

Tags: c#

I have

```
public class Lead
{
        public string LeadFirstName { get; set; }        
        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }       
}
public class Document
{
   public int DocumentId { get; set; }
   public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
}
```

When I am doing the below

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
lead.LeadFirstName = "Test";
lead.Documents.Add(new Document{ DocumentId  = 1, DocumentPath  = @"C:\test\abc.doc"});
```

I am getting Null Reference exception. - Why?

Comment: At which point in your code do you get it ?

Comment: Just a wild guess - try to do `lead.Documents = new List<Document>` before adding a document to your list

Comment: Initialize Documents in the default constructor:
`Documents = new List<Document>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not instantiating your list of documents. One way to do it would be via constructor:

```
public class Lead
{
    public Lead()
    {
        Documents = new List<Document>();
    }

    public string LeadFirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Document> Documents { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the collection:

```
 Lead lead = new Lead();
 lead.LeadFirstName = "Test";
 lead.Documents = new List<Document>(); <<-----
 lead.Documents.Add(new Document{ DocumentId  = 1, DocumentPath  = @"C:\test\abc.doc"});
```